# Shared preference

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, bundle

I developed one app in that I want to send URI from Class1 editText to another class containing editText.
Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Comment: What does this have to do with shared preferences?

Answer (score 3):

SharedPreferences are the wrong way to do that. Use the `Bundle` feature every Intent can have: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

On the second activity you can call `getExtra()` and there you go...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to use the SharedPreferences to transfer the URI, you could try this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
prefs.edit().putString("my-uri", "http://google.com/").commit();
```

And to retrieve the URI:

```
prefs.getString("my-uri", "default URI");
```

If your two classes are Activities, and if one of them starts the other one, you should probably pass the URI as an intent extra.

Also, read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) and accept some answers!

Answer (score 0):

you can use System.setProperty/get Property as well.

Answer (score 0):

don't you like to add putExtra in intent

like this

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Audit_FSD_Tab.class);
            i.putExtra("UsrID", UsrID);
            i.putExtra("Store", Store);
            i.putExtra("location", location);
            startActivityForResult(i, 0);
```

now in other activity access these extra

```
     Bundle UsrVal = null;
        UsrVal = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    UsrID = UsrVal.getString("UserId");
    Store = UsrVal.getString("Store");
    location = UsrVal.getString("location");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to store Uri in the edit text inside  shared preferences in first activity and then on create method of second activity retrieve Uri value from the shared preferences and display that in edit text.simple...

Answer (score 0):

It can be possible by using Shared Preferences, for example

```
 SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE); 
 Editor editor = pref.edit();
 data=pref.getString("key_name5", null);
 editText.setText(data);
```

You can follow [tutorial here](http://firstcode.info/android-sharedpreferences-basics/)

http://firstcode.info/android-sharedpreferences-basics/